# In SQL (Snowflake) how do I attribute earned premium to each month between a start date and an end date?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, finance

I have random example data below, but I am trying to spread the cost of a policy accurately over its policy term. So the policy will be in force for a different number of days for different months. I do not know how to attribute the correct cost to each month based on their start and end date.
Using the below example, the first policy would run for 16 days in January (which is £44.36) and then runs for 28 days in February (which is £77.64). I would like to have those amounts in the relevant column but I can't get my head around how to do this in SQL.
[image]
Any advice would be very much appreciated, thank you!
Aware it should be JAN23 etc not JAN22.

Answer (score 0):

You know when you start something you wish you didn't ...

Basically -> push the start+end dates into a list of all dates between them, pull out the start and end of each month, adjusting for the actual start_date and end_date. Then ... sigh ... ratio_to_report gets the split you're after. Then we pivot to get the months. I know there's a nicer way to get the titles ... but I just wanted this answer to end I'm sorry. Oh yes before you start take your image and turn it into a CTE.

[image]

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 122  GROSS_WRITTEN_PREMIUM, 'Bk4Zw' POLICY_NUMBER,'2023-01-17' START_DATE,'2023-03-01' END_DATE, 44 POLICY_LENGTH UNION ALL   
SELECT 85  GROSS_WRITTEN_PREMIUM,'TMFti' POLICY_NUMBER,'2023-01-18' START_DATE,'2023-03-02' END_DATE, 44 POLICY_LENGTH UNION ALL       
SELECT 132  GROSS_WRITTEN_PREMIUM,'DI2iz' POLICY_NUMBER,'2023-01-19' START_DATE,'2023-03-03' END_DATE, 44 POLICY_LENGTH UNION ALL     
SELECT 159  GROSS_WRITTEN_PREMIUM,'ObJwe' POLICY_NUMBER,'2023-01-20' START_DATE,'2023-03-04' END_DATE, 44 POLICY_LENGTH UNION ALL     
SELECT 137  GROSS_WRITTEN_PREMIUM,'4уХ9A' POLICY_NUMBER,'2023-01-21' START_DATE,'2023-03-05' END_DATE, 44 POLICY_LENGTH UNION ALL 
SELECT 181  GROSS_WRITTEN_PREMIUM,'KUxRy' POLICY_NUMBER,'2023-01-22' START_DATE,'2023-03-06' END_DATE, 44 POLICY_LENGTH UNION ALL
SELECT 149  GROSS_WRITTEN_PREMIUM,'oINkI' POLICY_NUMBER,'2023-01-23' START_DATE,'2023-03-07' END_DATE, 44 POLICY_LENGTH UNION ALL
SELECT 96  GROSS_WRITTEN_PREMIUM,'FJkV1' POLICY_NUMBER,'2023-01-24' START_DATE,'2023-03-08' END_DATE, 44 POLICY_LENGTH UNION ALL    
SELECT 152  GROSS_WRITTEN_PREMIUM,'Si4gd' POLICY_NUMBER,'2023-01-25' START_DATE,'2023-03-09' END_DATE, 44 POLICY_LENGTH UNION ALL
SELECT 80  GROSS_WRITTEN_PREMIUM,'МСфА3' POLICY_NUMBER,'2023-01-26' START_DATE,'2023-03-10' END_DATE, 44 POLICY_LENGTH UNION ALL   
SELECT 100  GROSS_WRITTEN_PREMIUM,'olvyl' POLICY_NUMBER,'2023-01-27' START_DATE,'2023-03-11' END_DATE, 44 POLICY_LENGTH UNION ALL
SELECT 102  GROSS_WRITTEN_PREMIUM,'UHEC' POLICY_NUMBER,'2023-01-28' START_DATE,'2023-03-12' END_DATE, 44 POLICY_LENGTH  )
,CTE2 AS (SELECT DISTINCT CTE.* 
,LEAST(END_DATE,LAST_DAY(DATEADD('DAY', INDEX,START_DATE )::DATE)) as SECOND_DATE
,GREATEST(START_DATE, DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', SECOND_DATE)) as  FIRST_DATE 
,ROUND(ratio_to_report(DATEDIFF(DAY,FIRST_DATE-1,SECOND_DATE))OVER(PARTITION BY POLICY_NUMBER)/POLICY_LENGTH*1000*GROSS_WRITTEN_PREMIUM,2) EASY_PEASY 
,UPPER(MONTHNAME(FIRST_DATE)) MONTH_NAME         
FROM CTE , LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(REPEAT('hire me $10/hour',POLICY_LENGTH),'hire me $10/hour')ALTERNATIVE_APPROACH
 )

SELECT GROSS_WRITTEN_PREMIUM, POLICY_NUMBER, START_DATE,END_DATE,POLICY_LENGTH, SUM($8) JAN, SUM($9)FEB,SUM($10)MAR FROM CTE2
PIVOT (SUM(EASY_PEASY) FOR MONTH_NAME in ('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR'))
GROUP BY GROSS_WRITTEN_PREMIUM, POLICY_NUMBER, START_DATE,END_DATE,POLICY_LENGTH;
```